# Building dependencies of dependents and dependents of dependencies

Tags: maven, maven-reactor

The `-am` (also make dependencies) and `-amd` (also make dependents) command line options can be used together but they will not work transitively to e.g. make the dependents of a dependency. E.G. will

```
$ mvn  -amd -am -pl test:c clean
```

build `b`, `c` and `d` - but *not* `a` or `e` given the following reactor (groupId=`test`) module dependency graph:

[image: dependency graph]

I'd like to build *all* modules that could have been affected by a code change in e.g. `c` - is that possible in maven? I guess this is equivalent to all vertices that is reachable from `c`, i.e. in this case all modules except `f` and `g`.

Comment: The question is what kind of problem are you trying to solv? Why is it necessary to  select such dependency graph instead of simply building the project?

Comment: It might be a valid scenario in a monorepo setup where you want not always build everything but rather use the dependency handling features of maven to just build what can have been affected (even though in the likely case of intertwined dependencies this maybe very well be the same as building the whole project)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There aren't any options in Maven to achieve what you like to have. The `-amd` option will traverse the whole module tree *below* the specified module (`c` in your example). The `-am` option will traverse the path to the root of your module tree.